# Coded ui- How to update properties of object in UImap.uitest file which has changed in application?

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Coded ui- How to update properties of object in UImap.uitest file which has changed in application? for example a window which has version of software changes with every build. The issue is if I try to record anything on new version of software it creates new objects in UImap and the whole object tree again. This makes UImap too huge adding duplicates of objects with slightly different property.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to update the properties to latest, but make the property values dynamic.  Just updating the properties will mean more work the next time your code changes.

Also, try to only use properties to search on that do not change between application runs/versions.  Example, a `class` property will likely remain static between runs, while the title of your parent window may change based on the version number.  Check out [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg269469.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to see how to modify the recording's search properties to fit your needs, specifically the section on modifying UI action properties.

Another method to look into would be to create the objects and methods yourself using C#.  By adding controls yourself to the uimap.cs partial class of the .uitest, you have can specify at design time what properties and values that Coded UI uses to execute your tests.